# DynamoDB UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES does not Apply to Complex Nested Properties

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-mapper

I would like to update a single field in a nested property in DynamoDB. I figured using the `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` `SaveConfiguration` would allow me to do this, but that appears to not be the case.

My `DynamoDBTable`:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "users")
public class User {
    @DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName = "Id")
    @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
    private String id;

    @DynamoDBAtribute
    private String phone;

    @DynamoDBAtribute
    @DynamoDBTypeConvertedJson(targetType = Name.class)
    private Name name;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @DynamoDBDocument
    public static class Name {
        @DynamoDBAttribute
        private String first;

        @DynamoDBAttribute
        private String last;
    }
}
```

I have a `DynamoDBMapperConfig` initialized like so:

```
private final DynamoDBMapperConfig config = DynamoDBMapperConfig.builder().withSaveBheavior(DynamoDBMapperConfig.SaveBehavior.UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES).build();
```

And to save the record, I call the following:

```
mapper.save(user, config);
```

where `mapper` is a `DynamoDBMapper` and `user` is a `User` shown above.

The issue is that despite using the `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` configuration, if `user.name.last` is null, the DB record's `last` field gets updated to `null` as well instead of the field being ignored.

This issue does not occur for non-nested fields, such as `phone` - if `phone` is `null`, the record's current value does **not** get overwritten.

Is there a way to make `UPDATE_SKIP_NULL_ATTRIBUTES` apply to nested objects as well? I simply need a way to modify single fields in nested objects.